# django-avatar form location issue

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django/python and I'm using the django-avatar plugin (https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-avatar) so users can upload images as avatars on our website.

I've been trying to debug this issue for a day and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

The issue I'm running into is that I copied the "change.html" form into our myaccount.html page and I get the following:

"You haven't uploaded an avatar yet. Please upload one now."

That's incorrect since I already have an image uploaded and all I want is the proper change form with the input field to appear that populates once an avatar is uploaded. The form I want generated appears properly when I navigate to "/avatar/change/" when i want it to be "/myaccount/change/".

Does anyone have any ideas how  to solve this issue?

Thanks!

myacccount.html

```
<p>{% trans "Your current avatar: " %}</p>
{% avatar user %} {% if not avatars %}
 <p>{% trans "You haven't uploaded an avatar yet. Please upload one now." %}</p>
 {% else %}
 {% endif %}
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'avatar_add' %}">
 {{ upload_avatar_form.as_p }}
 <p>{% csrf_token %}
 <input type="submit" value="{% trans " Upload New Image " %}" />
 </p>
 </form>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Post

from django.views.generic import TemplateView


# Create your views here.
def homePageView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World!');

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class MyAccountView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'myaccount.html'    

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_posts_list'
```

urls.py

```
# pages/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings

from .views import HomePageView, MyAccountView, AboutPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('myaccount/', MyAccountView.as_view(), name='myaccount'),
    url('avatar/', include('avatar.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just changed the file location settings and now I got it working. Thanks.